# How to achieve synchronization between tablets running a hybrid app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, synchronization, tablet

I have an app built using Cordova and Ionic framework and I am planning to implement an "online version" for it. However, I have come to a point where I don't know what is the best approach.

**Current Scenario:**
This app is used by junior students where they need to select their school name, their grades and their divisions. Once these settings are configured, they can take up some simple tasks within the app. Each task can be unlocked by a "Code". They also receive points/score and can take notes for every task. Currently, these codes are announced by their teacher which the pupils then have to enter manually in their individual tablets to unlock a task. Also the notes and the points are stored locally within the device local storage.

**What I want to do:**
I now want to make an online version, where the teacher too would carry tablets with them called the "Guide" tablet. The teacher would then enter the code for each task on the guide tablet and the task should automatically be unlocked on the pupils tablet. Also the teacher should be able to view the scores of the students (or lets say scores stored on each tablet). I may want to add a few other options like a RESET feature/Feedback feature, etc that the teacher can perform on their tablets.
So basically, what I intend to do is perform some type of real time syncing and sharing of data between the tablets and sending quick push-notifications between them. I will be having an internet connection for the online version.

My app is built using Ionic. I am searching for the available approaches that would help me to implement this. I am open to any advice. 
Thanking you in advance.
Chaitra

Answer (score 1):

You could use a database field for it. You create a table with the "games" and you have for each student a row with "field_reset" and with your Ajax you check each X seconds if this field is set on 1 for example. If it is you simply execute your Javascript code for it.

You can do this too for "field_allowed" or anything. The teacher would have a list of pupils and a button to allow them to us it. Which would simply change the field in the database for that pupil.

Comment: Thnks !! Do correct me if I am wrong, but with this approach don't I have to poll the database or the server frequently? What I really want is for some type of event based trigger or notification that would be initiated from the main tablet and all the other devices should act a certain way (in my use case display a task based on the code entered) upon receiving it.

Comment: I personally don't know if there is another way that works without making requests to the database. Just know that this type of requests are quite fast and don't ask for a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna have a look at Firebase (which integrates well with Ionic v1 and v2; google for "Angularfire"/"Angularfire2"). It's providing a cloud based database with real-time synchronization, and is very easy to implement.

https://firebase.google.com/